# How to fill all unify properties from one object to other object in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

**How to fill all unify properties from one object to other object considering Property Name.**

for example, i have two classes A & B and some properties are same in both whereas some are not same.

What expectation is, Transform all unify properties value from class-A to class-B considering property-name so if property name matches in both then value assign into target class property and if does not match then keep as-is.

in following example, I want to know how to write a generic function like named **TransformValues**  which can convert values in between two classes .

here is the sample code:

```
class A {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyCustomType MyValues{ get; set; }
}
class B {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyCustomType MyValues{ get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
class MyCustomType {
    public int MyId { get; set; }
    public string MyName { get; set; }
}



private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        A classA = new A(){Id=1, Name="Name01", MyValues=new MyCustomType(){MyId=10, MyName="MyNameValue01"}};
        B classB = new B(){Id=2, Name="Name02", MyValues=new MyCustomType(){MyId=20, MyName="MyNameValue02"}, Address="My Address"};

        classB = TransformValues(classA, classB);
    }

private T  TransformValues(classA A, classB B){
   ............   Need Function Code here By experts    ............
};
```

So based on above sample code,

```
classB = TransformValues(classA, classB);
```

this function should transform classA values (Id, Name, MyCustomType) into classB whereas Address property value will remain as is or null.

Comment: Have you heard of AutoMapper? http://automapper.org/

Comment: You can use reflection for that I guess. Or take a look at TypeDescriptor class.

Comment: ok thx for quick comments, can u suggest code pls?

Comment: The simplest algorithm would be to get properties of both objects and compare them. You will have to use nested iteration. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Self found, posting cause may help others.

USAGE:

```
classB = TransformValues(classA, new B());
```

FUNCTION:

```
public static T TransformValues<T>(object source, T destination)
{
    try {
        // If any this null throw an exception
        if (source == null || destination == null)
            throw new Exception("Source or/and Destination Objects are null");
        // Getting the Types of the objects
        Type typeDest = destination.GetType();
        Type typeSrc = source.GetType();

        // Iterate the Properties of the source instance and  
        // populate them from their desination counterparts  
        PropertyInfo[] srcProps = typeSrc.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo srcProp in srcProps) {
            if (!srcProp.CanRead) {
                continue;
            }
            PropertyInfo targetProperty = typeDest.GetProperty(srcProp.Name);
            if (targetProperty == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!targetProperty.CanWrite) {
                continue;
            }
            if (targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true) != null && targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true).IsPrivate) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((targetProperty.GetSetMethod().Attributes & MethodAttributes.Static) != 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!targetProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(srcProp.PropertyType)) {
                continue;
            }
            // Passed all tests, lets set the value
            targetProperty.SetValue(destination, srcProp.GetValue(source, null), null);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
    }
    return destination;
}
```